# Does marking Javascript Remoting "buffer: false" really make it async?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

Lets say I have 5 VF pages in a flexipage, each VF page has Javascript remoting which queries on different objects. Javascript remoting is marked as `buffer: false`.

Now as we know Apex is single threaded application, will these 5 requests go and hit apex methods in a synchronous manner or every request will have its own thread and will work in async manner?

Does action function has any benefit over remoting performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

> Now as we know Apex is single threaded application, will these 5
>   requests go and hit apex methods in a synchronous manner or every
>   request will have its own thread and will work in async manner?

VF remoting never works in an asynchronous manner. If you check the debug log it has all the limitations of the synchronous process. Buffer = true , used to group all the requests and fire them at once, but if you make buffer = false , it will fire for every request, making every request as a single transaction.

> Does action function has any benefit over remoting performance-wise?

VFremoting has more power over action function and they are used in different scenarios.
Suppose you want a VF page to display only 100 records from 1 million records. If you go for action function there are chances of hitting limit exceptions like SOQL limit/heap size/CPU time out. But if you call a VF remoting method from a loop(after knowing whats the total number of records and how many time you have to call apex method), you can get the data in chunks of 10,000 records, store it in a js array by making buffer = false and escape = false.Then after you loop finish you can sort and display top 100 records.